# Call WebService with verification

Tags: google-apps-script

I created this web service:

```
function doPost(e) {
  if(typeof e !== 'undefined');

var  doc = DocumentApp.create(e.parameter.name);
  var body = doc.getBody();
 body.appendParagraph(e.parameter.text);

 return ContentService.createTextOutput(doc.getId());  
}
```

Deploy as web app: Anyone within my domain

How can I now call this service using another apps script?
I can use UrlFetchApp?
How to add verification to a call?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

How about following sample script? Data of `name` and `text` is sent to the URL using the POST method. The URL can be retrieved when the script with `doPost()` is deployed as Web Apps.

#### Sample script :

```
var url = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/#####/exec";
var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
  method: "post",
  payload: {
    name: "samplename",
    text: "sampletext",
  }
});
Logger.log(res)
```

By this request, `name` and `text` can be used as `e.parameter.name` and `e.parameter.text` at `doPost(e)`, respectively.

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.